# How to sapply a vector on a user defined function in R

Tags: r, function, sapply

I have a user defined function called `make_data` for creating dataset.
I need to generate 3 different datasets using the `make _data` and `mu_1 <- seq(1:3)`. I don't know how to use `sapply`, since the `make_data` function has multiple arguments,

```
library(dplyr) # for `%>%` and `slice`
library(caret) # for createDataPartion
make_data <- function(n = 1000, p = 0.5, 
                  mu_0 = 0, mu_1 = 2, 
                  sigma_0 = 1,  sigma_1 = 1){



 y <- rbinom(n, 1, p)
  f_0 <- rnorm(n, mu_0, sigma_0)
  f_1 <- rnorm(n, mu_1, sigma_1)
  x <- ifelse(y == 1, f_1, f_0)

  test_index <- createDataPartition(y, times = 1, p = 0.5, list = FALSE)

  list(train = data.frame(x = x, y = as.factor(y)) %>% slice(-test_index),
       test = data.frame(x = x, y = as.factor(y)) %>% slice(test_index))
}
```

## using sapply function

```
mu_1 <- seq(0, 3)
dat_3<- sapply(mu_1,make_data)
```

I am getting an error report as shown below.

> Error in `createDataPartition(y, times = 1, p = 0.5, list = FALSE)` : 
>     y must have at least 2 data points.

Comment: The first time `make_data` is called is with `n=0`, so you effectively do `rbinom(0, 1, p)` which returns a vector of length 0. How do you expect to create a partition on zero data? (Similarly, 1 is insufficient, since the error suggests it needs *"at least 2 data points"*. I'd start with `mu_1 <- seq(2, 4)` or similar.

Comment: For `mu1` being 0 or 1 your function will do `... createDataPartition(0, times = 1, p = 0.5, list = FALSE) ...` and that seems to throw the error.

Comment: @r2evans So should i define all the arguments again in 'sapply' function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error arises because your argument, `mu_1` was being position-matched, not to the `mu_1` in your `make_data` function, but rather to the `n` argument. To pass an argument to a "non-first" parameter in a function where all the other parameters have acceptable defaults in the definition, you need to encapsulate that "out of sequence" parameter in an anonymous function and then accept it as a named parameter:

```
 library(dplyr) # for `%>%` and `slice`
 library(caret) # for createDataPartion
 # your code here
 dat_3<- sapply(mu_1, function(param) make_data(mu_1=param))  #succeeds
```

The `n` parameter is now the 1000 that you clearly intended it to be.

```
str(dat_3)
List of 8
 $ :'data.frame':   500 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ x: num [1:500] 2.963 0.313 0.853 -1.154 -1.895 ...
  ..$ y: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 ...
 $ :'data.frame':   500 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ x: num [1:500] -1.288 1.245 -0.109 -0.794 0.11 ...
  ..$ y: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 ...
 $ :'data.frame':   500 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ x: num [1:500] -0.686 1.823 -0.052 1.189 -0.318 ...
  ..$ y: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 ...
 $ :'data.frame':   500 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ x: num [1:500] -0.623 0.311 1.298 0.848 1.17 ...
  ..$ y: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 1 2 1 1 2 1 2 2 1 ...
 $ :'data.frame':   500 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ x: num [1:500] 0.956 0.825 1.592 2.729 -0.299 ...
  ..$ y: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ :'data.frame':   500 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ x: num [1:500] 1.92059 3.29866 0.00569 0.38111 0.41855 ...
  ..$ y: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 ...
 $ :'data.frame':   500 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ x: num [1:500] 4.572 3.19 -0.598 3.744 0.463 ...
  ..$ y: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 1 2 1 2 1 1 2 2 ...
 $ :'data.frame':   500 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ x: num [1:500] 2.7439 -0.0985 -0.4698 -1.2808 0.6663 ...
  ..$ y: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 - attr(*, "dim")= int [1:2] 2 4
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "train" "test"
  ..$ : NULL
```

That got rid of the error but the datasets did not get the names you intended. That was because `sapply` removed them due to its "simplification" process (which is the `s` in `sapply`). You should instead use `lapply`. This then gives you named dataframes and they will be embedded in a list structure that you can properly iterate over, rather than the "simplified" result from `sapply`:

```
  dat_3<- lapply(mu_1, function(x) make_data(mu_1=x))
```

I started out thinking I would answer the question by deploying `traceback()` and showing how to debug and basically expand on the comments, but that got me nowhere. I realized that the actions of `sapply`/`lapply` on named objects was at the root of the problem. It's a stumbling block that has frustrated many new and old users of R. Only the values and not the names are passed to the function. The responsibility for properly accepting arguments for any but the first is left entirely to the user. And not even the names of values destined to the first argument make it through. When you "say" `lapply(obj_name, FUN)` ... it turns out that `FUN` doe NOT get `obj_name` but only the result of `eval(objname)`.

Comment: it worked, Thanks for the help. you saved my moral :)